# How to retrive text written on canvas as string

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have written text on canvas using filltext(). Now in another function i want to retrieve that value as string. If anyone could help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Why? That's like saying "I typed a a page on a typewriter and put it through a photocopier, now how can I read that back into a text file?". You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: I am taking input from the user using prompt and writing using fillText(). Now I want to check whether all the characters input by him are correct

Comment: @VijetaKarani Just *save the written value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This w3c article might be of interest to you:](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Reading_text_in_canvas)

> When an author renders text on a canvas with fillText or strokeText,
>   they must also add an html element (div or span) with the same text,
>   styling and position to the canvas subdom. The bounding box of the
>   text should be set with the setElementPath method (See
>   http://www.w3.org/wiki/Canvas_hit_testing)
>
> This enables user agents to use the subdom text to deliver an
>   accessible experience, as the subdom text acts as a proxy for the
>   rendered text in the bitmap.

[And here's an example built for accessibility:](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/09/html5-canvas-accessibility-in-internet-explorer-9/)

```
<canvas id="example" width="260" height="200" role="img">   <p>A <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle">rectangle</a> with a black border. In the background is a pink circle. Partially overlaying the circle is a green square and a purple triangle, both of which are semi-opaque, so the full circle can be seen underneath.</p>   </canvas>
```

So all you need to do is when the user enters text, store it within a div inside the canvas element.

Answer (score 3):

When you write the text to the canvas, also add a custom property to the canvas object containing the text itself. When you want to check it, simply query that property. So:

```
myCanvas.getContext("2d").filltext(theText,x,y,maxWidth);
myCanvas.addedText = theText;
```

And later,

```
var textToCheck = myCanvas.addedText;
```